# Ruby on Rails 4 and cocoon gem : How to interrupt deletion on cocoon:before-remove

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, coffeescript, cocoon-gem

I'm looking for a way to do a more sophisticated confirm that the one I use right now that look like this :

```
     <%= link_to_remove_association "<i class='icon-remove-sign'></i>".html_safe, 
      p, :class => 'btn-link remove has-tooltip',
     :data => {:original_title => "Delete phone", 
     :confirm => 'Are you sure you want to delete this phone?'} %>
```

I just want to avoid the confirm dialog if the phone entry is blank.

I think there must be a way in the 'cocoon:before-remove' event but I can't manage to find it ?

For example, in a Coffesecript function like this :

```
$(document).delegate '.phones', 'cocoon:before-remove', (e, item) ->

    tel = $(item).find('.tel .form-control')
    conf = true
    if tel.val().trim() != ''
      conf = confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this phone?')

    if conf
      $(@).data('remove-timeout', 1000)
      item.fadeOut('slow')
    else
      #stop deletion!!

    conf
```

Any clue ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that cocoon is missing this functionality, however I just forked the repo and added it. For now, you can do as follows:

Change in your gemfile:

```
gem 'cocoon', git: 'https://github.com/BroiSatse/cocoon.git'
```

Then modify your handler:

```
$(document).delegate '.phones', 'cocoon:before-remove', (e, item, result) ->

  tel = $(item).find('.tel .form-control')
  conf = true
  if tel.val().trim() != ''
    conf = confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this phone?')

  if conf
    $(@).data('remove-timeout', 1000)
    item.fadeOut('slow')
  else
    result.val = false
```

Note the extra param for the handler.

Comment: Wow thanks a lot ! I am just testing it by now and it work like a charm... I love open source community and GitHub :-)

Comment: Just note, that this might be misleading for a customer, as the record is not deleted until the form is submitted. If customer confirm he want to delete it and then navigate back, he might be surprised.

Answer (score 1):

Actually you can call **event.preventDefault()** inside your handler for 'cocoon:before-remove'.

Preventing the event default behavior will cancel the remove operation.